# Error: can't assign to literal in python- Figured out my error

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow. I am new to the concept of mapper and reducer. I have an assignment on it. I have a csv file which contains labor rate for different countries for the years 2007-2016. I am trying to write a code which gives me the country which has the highest average rate. I am writing this in python and getting an error can't assign to literal.I am getting this error at the first mapper step.Please help! Below is my  code:

```
def steps(self):
    return [
        MRStep(mapper=self.mapper_get_Country_Name,
                   reducer=self.reducer_Average_rate),
        MRStep(mapper=self.mapper_make_Average_key,
                         reducer=self.reducer_output_Country_Name)
    ]

def mapper_get_Country_Name(self, key, line):
    (SeriesName, SeriesCode, CountryName, CountryCode,2007,2008,
     2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,
     2015,2016)=line.split(',')
    yield CountryName, float(Average_rate)

def reducer_Average_rate(self, CountryName, Average_rate):
    yield CountryName, Average_rate

def mapper_make_Average_key(self, CountryName, Average_rate):
    yield float(Average_rate), CountryName


def reducer_output_Country_Name(self,Average_rate, CountryName):
        yield max(Average_rate), CountryName
```

Comment: `2007` and `2008` etc aren't valid names for variables.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for looking at it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is in this line:

```
(SeriesName, SeriesCode, CountryName, CountryCode,2007,2008,
 2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,
 2015,2016)=line.split(',')
```

Python allows you to assign parts of a line to a bunch of variables, and the first four items will be taken as variable names. However, the items after this are numbers. A number is a literal value - that is, it cannot be used as a name for anything else - 2016 only means 20 16.

However, if you are uninterested in these values there are a few ways to ignore them.

First you can use the "_" underscore syntax, which in python will mean "ignore this value":

```
(SeriesName, SeriesCode, CountryName, CountryCode, _, _,
     _, _, _, _, _, _,
     _, _)=line.split(',')
```

Now this is clearly a little tedious. 
Instead you could chop the list for the four first items and assign only them:

```
SeriesName, SeriesCode, CountryName, CountryCode = line.split(',')[:4]
```

The "[:4]" syntax means only the first 4 items - the operation is known as slicing.
This also means another set of parenthesis can be dropped since it's on one line.

Comment: Note, `_` is just like any other valid identifier, there is nothing special about it. It is merely *convention* that it is used for variables to be ignored.

Comment: It is, but it is a convention that linters can deal with as opposed to moaning about unreferenced variables, and a reasonable convention for stripping values. Although I'll admit I prefer the second form.

Answer (score 1):

For the next questions, please include the error itself. It includes a lot of useful information. That would make for a better question that doesn't get down-voted and does get quality answers faster.

Your issue seems to be with:

```
(SeriesName, SeriesCode, CountryName, CountryCode,2007,2008,
 2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,
 2015,2016)=line.split(',')
```

You are basically trying to do:

```
2007 = line.split(',')[4]
2008 = line.split(',')[5]
# etc.
```

You can't assign a new value to a literal. `2007` is a literal and not a variable. That's the error you're getting. You probably want something like:

```
(SeriesName, SeriesCode, CountryName, CountryCode,v_2007,v_2008,
 v_2009,v_2010,v_2011,v_2012,v_2013,v_2014,
 v_2015,v_2016)=line.split(',')
```

You then probably need to calculate the actual average or you're going to get an error for the next line where `Average_rate` is not defined.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have rectified the error and now trying to calculate the average rate within python.